# Python processes appearing and disappearing in top

Tags: python, performance, top, cluster, load

I concurrently launched around 12 Python scripts on a 24-core server (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS x64). Each of Python script takes around one hour to complete.

I see in top that they appear quite sporadically, whereas each script is supposed to take at least 100% of one core without interruption (there is no disk IO involved, no network IO, and no swap as of the server has around 100 GB of RAM and the script RAM requirements are pretty light):

[image]

What can explain that in top each script doesn't continuously take 100% CPU for one core or more?

The 24-core server is part of a computer cluster, but typically if there is some  overload the `st` in top would explain it. (i.e. be far more than 0.0).

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing your kernel doesn't see them as prioritary :)

If you have a look at your image, you can see that your Python processes have a priority of 20. That's the default value. This means that if we take aside other scheduling factors (already-allocated CPU time, process state, ...), your Python scripts are considered just as important as `top`, `rcu_shed`, `sshd`, ... Now, while these processes might not always have stuff to do, they still get access to the CPU whenever they enter [the RUNNING state](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/tlk/kernel/processes.html).

Linux processes run in time quantums (or time slices). This means that every *n* milliseconds, the kernel *preempts* (suspends) the currently running process (on a core), and searches for another process to schedule. By defaut, the time slice value is 100 msecs ([or so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16402758/2228310)).

Since your machine has 24 cores, you can basically assume that 24 processes can be scheduled to run simultaneously. The (24) processes which are selected (every 100 msecs) for scheduling are chosen based on several factors. Besides, a process may also be preempted if it enters a sleeping state before its time slice expires. As of Linux 2.6, the kernel uses the [Completely Fair Scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_Fair_Scheduler) algorithm by default. Process scheduling priority is mostly based on the time each process has spent running already, and takes "user priority" (niceness) into account through a [*decay factor*](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-completely-fair-scheduler/):

> CFS doesn't use priorities directly but instead uses them as a decay factor for the time a task is permitted to execute. **Lower-priority tasks have higher factors of decay, where higher-priority tasks have lower factors of delay.** This means that the time a task is permitted to execute dissipates more quickly for a lower-priority task than for a higher-priority task. That's an elegant solution to avoid maintaining run queues per priority.

Now, it is possible (from userland) to run a process with a custom niceness value through the `nice` command :

```
nice [OPTION] [COMMAND [ARG]...]
    Run  COMMAND  with an adjusted niceness, which affects  process scheduling. 
    With no COMMAND, print the  current niceness. Niceness  values range  from 
    -20 (most favorable to the process) to 19 (least favorable to the process).
```

Simply keep in mind that the Linux scheduler doesn't use that priority as an absolute thing. This value will be factored in whenever the kernel needs the select a process, but other factors will also be taken into account: your processes' greediness makes them a lot less likely to be selected anyway <sub>(the algorithm's name is quite self-explanatory on that one :p)</sub>.

Comment: This doesn't answer the actual title issue, though, which I too am encountering.  Even if I filter `top` by the Python process's PID, that one line appears and disappears seemingly at random.  The task clearly isn't exiting, because it's still the same PID.